# Sniffing queries to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to sniff SQL queries sent to a SQL Server db on any level (above transport level)?   Perhaps there's some kind of a tracer in ASP.NET or built-in log in SQL Server ?

Answer (score 11):

SQL Server Profiler perhaps?  This will pick up what queries are executed.  You can also get statistics, query plans and many other items of interest from this.

Answer (score 5):

When you are in SQL Management Studio, open the query editor and set it to the correct database you would like to profile.
Run the following query:

```
select db_id()
```

That will tell you your database id .

- Go to Tools > SQL Profile Manager.
- Click file > New trace ...
- Connect to your database server.
- On the window that shows up, click on the Events Selection tab.
- Click the Show All Columns checkbox.
- Then click Column Filters and choose DatabaseID in the Edit Filter box.

  On the right, choose "Equals" and put in the database id from the query above.
- Click OK and then Run.

Comment: You can also filter by database name directly.

Answer (score 4):

The tool your looking for is [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx), learn to use it and to love it.

Try starting with a filter on ApplicationName and/or HostName for your IIS server running your ASP.NET application. Profiler can get quite chatty.